# Need command-fedora-keyboard navigation key substitution in TCL script for a switch (CLI)

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

I have a switch (CLI based) that takes me to the present STP setting when you hit the alphabets (which iam able to automate with tcl) but when it comes to changing the STP setting say from RSTP to MSTP, manually, I have to hit the *up arrow* and *down arrow* keys( only option available).

I need help to give the up arrow and down arrow commands in tcl format to automate it.

I read about rlwrap but thats more of history/ file editing which may not be helpful for me.
I have tried the " ^[[A" and "[A"  options and hexacodes with no success.

I have tried "\u001b[A" etc but the value STP does not change. The CLI is A XML CLI. This is my script . 
  spawn telnet $DUT1_IP expect "login:" send "$user\r" expect "Password:" send "$password\r" expect "sh-3.2#" #sleep 2 send "xml_cli\r" expect ">> " send "bridge_config_mode = STP"

If i have to change mode STP to MSTP i need to use up arrow key in my keyboard to change it to MSTP /RSTP . how to use in expect to handle the same . Please give your thoughts if we can use shell scripting for the same (or any other).

Thanks and Regards
Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Up</kbd> is mapped by your system keyboard driver to a three-character sequence: `^[[A`. The first character, rendered as `^[` here, is an *Escape* character that is not normally renderable on your screen, and you write a real one in a Tcl script with `\u001b`. <kbd>Down</kbd> is correspondingly `^[[B`. (Strictly, it could be other character sequences — it depends on the terminal type after all — but virtually everything uses the same thing here, and thank goodness!)

Let's simplify things for you by putting those key sequences in variables (we also need a backslash before the real `[` because it is a Tcl metasyntax character):

```
set up   "\u001b\[A"
set down "\u001b\[B"
```

Now you can do this to send the characters to the remote side:

```
send $up
expect "...whatever..."
send $down
expect "...blah..."
```

Comment: @ Donal, I will try and update you and by the way I am not spawning any process after I expect login to switch, only TCLing. But I am sure that if i write "\^[OA" as you suggested, it should work. My switch sees "^[OA" as up arrow.. Best Regards, Mo

Comment: @code You set it to whatever you need it to be set to. There are some ways to get key sequences without being dependent on a particular terminal type (e.g., via calling the `tput` program) but it's usually easier to just make things work in one place for one setup. Often that's all you need.

Comment: @ Donal   I have tried your suggestion "\u001b\[A" etc but the value _STP_ does not change.  This is my script .
<pre> <code> spawn telnet $DUT1_IP
    expect "login:"
    send "$user\r"
    expect "Password:"
    send "$password\r"
    expect "sh-3.2#"
    #sleep 2
    send "xml_cli\r"
    expect ">> "

    send "bridge_config_mode  = STP"
If i have to change mode to MSTP i need to use up arrow key in my keyboard to change it to MSTP /RSTP .
 how to use in expect to handle the same .                         Please give your thoughts if we can use shell scripting for the same (or any other).

Comment: I even tried the "\^[OA" , but failed. I would also try the tput method you had suggested before. Thank you so much. Best Regards, Mo

Comment: Please let me know if we could use shell scripting for this task. Any other idea is also welcome. Thanks in advance, Regards, Mo